# Include an existing XML layout file in another XML layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I have a LinearLayout defined in a file called intro_step1_activity.xml. I would like to load/reference this file in another xml file so that I do not need to retype the code in the other xml file. Is this possible and if so how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime you can use an inflater, for instance:

```
Inflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro_step1_activity, null);
```

then you can add this view to the current view hierarchy. At compile time you can use the include tag for the xml

```
<include layout="@layout/intro_step1_activity"/>
```

Comment: From Android documentation:
It is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or getSystemService(String) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly configured for the device you are running on. For example:
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 3):

```
Load an existing xml layout file in another xml layout file
```

to use xml file in other xml file use `<include />`

for your `intro_step1_activity.xml` use code

```
<include layout="intro_step1_activity.xml"/>
```

Comment: `<include layout="@layout/my_layout_file"/>` seems to work also

Answer (score 0):

first give an `id` to that `LinearLayout` and then define a `LinearLayout` in java and reference it using the `findViewById()` method.

then use the `LinearLayout` object you just created to call the `addView()` method.

if you want an example, comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using `<merge>` or `<include>`.

You can read more [here](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/03/01/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-part-1/) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#merge-element)